# Examples of different norms

Tags: normed-spaces

I have a line through $\mathbb{R}^n$, and an infinite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I am trying to show that I can find point in my set arbitrarily close to the line. To do this; I was going to use the normal Euclidean norm to find the shortest distance between an arbitrary point $a = (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and the line $x(t) = (x_1t+c_1, x_2t+c_2,...,x_nt+c_n)$, but assuming I did the algebra correctly the formula for this distance:

$$\text{min}(|a-x(t)|) = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n\big(a_i-c_i-x_i\frac{\sum_{j = 1}^n x_j(a_j-c_j)}{\sum_{j = 1}^nx_j^2}\big)^2}$$

isn't nice looking at all. I then realised that I didn't actually need to use the normal Euclidean norm, because all I am trying to show is that there are points in my set arbitrarily close to my line; I can use any other norm that 'sort of agrees on closeness', for instance I could use the $l_1$ Manhattan distance norm. But this doesn't seem like a great norm to use for this situation either, because it isn't obvious to me how to even go about finding the minimum distance between a point and a line:

$$\text{min}(||a-x(t)||_1) = \text{min}\big(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i - x_it-c_i|\big)$$

are there any norms that would be suited to this kind of application?

Comment: Suppose the infinite set you have is a line parallel to a given line. Then how can you find points that are arbitrarily close?

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda As in, I have an infinite set $A$, not an arbitrary infinite set

Comment: The statement is not true for an arbitrary infinite set $A\subset \mathbb R^n$. It is true if and only if there exists a sequence of points $a_n$ in $A$ which converge to a point $a\in \mathsf L$, where $\mathsf L$ is the given line.

Comment: @Math1000 I'm not trying to prove that it's true for arbitrary sets, I've constructed a specific set $A$ that I want to try and prove it's true (by using different norms)

Comment: @Math1000 using the normal Euclidean norm looks too finnicky in taking limits and things